# Should a PWA be a SPA too?

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I was wondering that because my app does have an initial journey that is totally diferente from the behaviour of the app.

I would like to separate this initial journey into a different "HTML" due data transfer and load time. Even **not** using the same framework (Angular2) as the rest of the app.

But this way the app is not a SPA anymore.

Does this harms the ["Connectivity independent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app#Characteristics) or ["App-like"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_web_app#Characteristics) PWA principles?

Obs. We are trying this because our researches shows direct relation between user engagement and speed of the loading time of initial tour.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the single-page app pattern for your web app means that you'll have a smooth transition to handling navigations cache-first in your progressive web app, using an [App Shell approach](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/architecture/app-shell).

Following the App Shell pattern isn't the only way to build a progressive web app, but if you take a different approach, you'll need to put more thought into how you cache your HTML, and you might have a harder time using a service worker to respond to navigation in a cache-first manner. Some of these considerations are outlined in this "[High-performance service worker loading](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/high-performance-loading)" article.

If your web app is currently a hybrid of a SPA along with a few static pages, then you can take that into account when you respond to [navigation requests](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/service-workers/high-performance-loading#first_what_are_navigation_requests) in your service worker by examining the incoming URL. Assuming there's a well-known prefix or other way of identifying whether a given URL corresponds to the SPA portion of your web app or the basic HTML portion, you can respond differently inside your `fetch` handler:

```
// Not shown: install and activate handlers to keep app-shell.html
// cached and up to date.
self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  if (event.request.mode === 'navigate' && event.request.url.includes('/spa'))
    event.respondWith(caches.match('app-shell.html'));
    return;
  }
  // Either do nothing, and your non-/spa URLs will go against the network,
  // or use a runtime caching strategy to handle your non-/spa URLs.
});
```

**Updated on 2018-06-21**: For an additional perspective, you can read "[Beyond SPAs: alternative architectures for your PWA](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/05/beyond-spa)"

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is [PWA](https://realtimewebapps.blogspot.com/p/what-is-progressive-web-app-aka-pwa.html) need not be [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application).

If we look at the documentation website of [Web Firm Framework](https://webfirmframework.github.io) you can see it is not an [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) but it is a [PWA](https://realtimewebapps.blogspot.com/p/what-is-progressive-web-app-aka-pwa.html). If we refresh the page while offline it works. We can also do "Add to home screen" in mobile chrome to add it as an app which brings App-like experience.

So to get an App-like experience your home page and some of its links must be able to be cached.